# Have a text from database to get a color out from what it says

Tags: php, css, mysql, database

Hey guys, im not good with coding so after failing to find out how from googling Im gonna try get help from the pros.

So, im just making something for fun cause im bored. I have a sql database with a table that consists of name, link and status.
The status has 3 options, Permanently Banned, Temporarily Banned and Kicked.

Currently I have it like this putting font color in the code, but then it all get in red text.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["name"]. " </td>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["link"]. "</td>
    <td class='text-left'><b><font color='red'> " . $row["status"] . "</font></b></td></tr>";

}
```

I want Permanently Banned to be in red, Temporarily Banned in orange and Kicked in green. I don't understand how to make the colors appear like that.

I appreciate any help, im still a newbie when it comes to coding so im sorry if this is a really easy solution that I failed to find :P

I also have a problem with the link, but im just gonna let it be for now, maybe I'l ask after this is fixed..

Thanks! :)

Comment: _Who upvotes questions this bad_

Comment: I think the `<font>` tag is so 1980's its actually deprecated

Comment: Oh, im so sorry for not being a professional coding nerd.

Comment: @RiggsFolly People trying to get the Civic Duty badge most likely. Just randomly clicking questions and voting without even reading.

Comment: There's no problem with being a beginner or making beginner mistakes @shittycoder There is a problem with the fact that you didn't read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're not showing any research efford on your own. Basicly your question is _How do I?_ while SO is about _I tried this, what went wrong?_

Comment: You're right @icecub . I'll make sure to have my next questions better filled out, with what I've tried or what not. As well as I'll make sure i read through the two topics you linked. Thanks

Comment: Don't worrie to much about it. New users to SO make these mistakes all the time. There's actually even a proposal going on for experienced users to help new users out in asking their first questions. You'll learn from it and ask better questions next time. And with some luck, you'll even be able to answer some as well :)

Comment: Maybe so, thanks again :)

Comment: For a first question it's not bad, I had enough information to provide an answer, as did other readers and it looks like OP put all their research and knowledge on the table here. We have code, explanation and its a relevant topic to many noobs out there (meaning this will get a lot of hits in search engines) lighten up guys, we have spent more effort in this comment thread than it took to help OP out in their coding journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a CSS class for each case and then style it via CSS. Of course you have to *clean* the name in order to remove spaces with underscore or hyphens.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cleanStatus = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $row["status"]));
    echo "<tr>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["name"]. " </td>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["link"]. "</td>
    <td class='text-left'><b class='".$cleanStatus."'> " . $row["status"] . "</b></td></tr>";
}
```

So your CSS could look like:

```
.permanently_banned {
   color: red;
}

.temporarily_banned {
   color: orange;
}

.kicked {
   color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your status as a CSS class:

```
$statusclass = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row[status]));`
```

then change your HTML for the status:

```
`<td class='text-left " . $statusclass . "'></td></tr>";`
```

Then add CSS to your output, preferably in the `<head>`, but anywhere might do:

```
<style type="text/css">
.permanently-banned { font-weight: bold; color: Red; }
.temporarily-banned { font-weight: bold; color: Orange; }
.kicked { font-weight: bold; color: Green; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that only affects the short example of code you provided might be to use an inline if

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["name"]. " </td>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["link"]. "</td>
    <td class='text-left'><b><font color='" . ($row["status"]=="Permanently Banned" ? "red" : ($row["status"]=="Temporarily Banned" ? "orange" : "green")) . "'> " . $row["status"] . "</font></b></td></tr>";
}
```

You could also do the conditional logic very easily in SQL, for new developers I often find this is an easier approach because it can be easier to manipulate the sql query than it might be to mess with the rendering code. You didn't provide your query, so I will assume what it is, (in future posts, please provide the sql query so we can provide a more complete solution) hopefully you can follow the switch logic and apply that to your own code:

```
SELECT name, link, status,
    CASE status 
        WHEN 'Permanently Banned' THEN 'Red' 
        WHEN 'Temporarily Banned' THEN 'Orange' 
        ELSE 'Green' 
    END as color 
FROM MyStatusTable
```

Then your rendering code is cleaner:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["name"]. " </td>
    <td class='text-left'> ". $row["link"]. "</td>
    <td class='text-left'><b><font color='" . $row["color"] . "'> " . $row["status"] . "</font></b></td></tr>";
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Of course the CSS solution by @morfie is not bad either. It comes down to what you're comfortable with maintaining at this stage in your code adventure.

Comment: drop the brackets ([]) in the query they are invalid MySQL code.. brackets are used within SQL-server.